# Syntax errors with interactive Sage cell

Tags: python, interactive, sage

I am trying to create a webpage which uses an interactive Sage cell to implement the Vigenere Cipher on user-inputted strings. Code runs perfectly when I run it outside of the interactive cell. See below:

```
message = 'Beware the Jabberwock, my son!'
key = 'VIGENERECIPHER'
from itertools import starmap, cycle                                                           
def encrypt(message, key):                                                                                                                           
    message = filter(lambda _: _.isalpha(), message.upper())                                                                                                   
    def enc(c,k): return chr(((ord(k) + ord(c)) % 26) + ord('A'))
        return "".join(starmap(enc, zip(message, cycle(key))))   
encr = encrypt(message, key)       
print encr
```

But when I try to implement it within the interactive cell, I get syntax errors.

```
@interact
def f(message = input_box('Beware the Jabberwock, my son!', label ="Plain text"), key = input_box('VIGENERECIPHER', label = "Key word")):
    from itertools import starmap, cycle                                                           
    def encrypt(message, key):                                                                                                                           
        message = filter(lambda _: _.isalpha(), message.upper())                                                                                                   
        def enc(c,k): return chr(((ord(k) + ord(c)) % 26) + ord('A'))                              
        return "".join(starmap(enc, zip(message, cycle(key))))   
    encr = encrypt(message, key)       
    print encr
```

The following error is printed:

```
AttributeError: 'exceptions.SyntaxError' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

I am new to python/sage... I'm guessing this is some sort of error with class/type? I've tried googling, but I can't find anything related to this problem specifically. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see this `AttributeError`, but another error instead. Maybe it's a sympton of the same thing. In any case, the problem is that `message=input_box(...)` expects a Python expression in the box. You should add a `type` keyword:

```
message=input_box('Beware the Jabberwock, my son!', label ="Plain text", type=str)
```

(Alternatively, you can enter all of your strings in the input box with explicit quotes.)